# smallest genereting set of the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

It is well known that the symmetric group $S_n$ is generated by the transpositions $(1\;2), (1\;3), ..., (1\;n)$. For $n\geq 3$ we can chose fewer elements to generate the $S_n$, namely $(1\;2)$ and $(1\;2\;...\;n)$. However if we count the elements with $order -1$ we get $n$ in both cases. Can we find a generating set such that we get $<n$ by counting the elements with $order-1$?

Comment: Actually in the case $(1 \; 2), (1 \; 3), ..., (1 \; n)$ your order $-1$ total would be $n-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing $n$ with $n-1$ (see the comment by @paw88789), the answer is yes (at least usually).

If $n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{e_i}$ for primes $p_i$ then $\langle (1,\ldots,n)\rangle=\langle\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k\rangle$ where $\sigma_i=(1,\ldots,n)^\frac{n}{p_i^{e_i}}$ has order $p_i^{e_i}$.

In particular, $S_n=\langle X\rangle$ with $X=\{(1,2),\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k\}$ and $\sum_{x\in X}(o(x)-1)$ is often less than $n-1$. For example, if $n=6$ we get $X=\{(1,2),(1,3,5)(2,4,6),(1,4)(2,5)(3,6)\}$ and $\sum_{x\in X}(o(x)-1)=1+1+2=4$

**Improvement**

I'm adding Derek Holt's comment below to my answer as it might be more useful to people stumbling across this.

> It is not hard to see that $S_n$ is generated by three elements of order 2: $=(1,)(2,−1)\cdots$, $=(2,)(3,−1)\cdots$, and $=(1,2)$. Note that $=(1,2,3,\ldots,)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you always find the lowest value by your method? And if not is a lowest value known?

Comment: it's certainly not always the lowest - in the case $n$ is prime my construction give a sum equal to $n$ which is beaten by your $n$ transpositions. I'm not aware of any least value.

Comment: It is not hard to see that $S_n$ is generated by three elements of order $2$: $a=(1,n)(2,n-1) \cdots$, $b=(2,n)(3,n-1) \cdots$, and $c=(1,2)$. Note that $ab = (1,2,3,\ldots,n)$.